# How to switch from Core Layout to Full Screen Layout? PageStack Header annoying

Tags: application-development, qml

I want switch from a [Core Layout to a Full Screen Layout](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps/global-patterns/layout) when clicking somewhere in the Core Layout.

I use

- `PageStack` to get the switching with back button and stuff
- `Tabs` to have something resembling the Core Layout out of the box and because I need it in the future to flick horizontally

My problem is, that `PageStack` introduces some dark header which is [nowhere seen in the design pages](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps/building-blocks/page-stack). I modified Ubuntu.Components.PageStack to expose the `header.visible` property to fix this for my app in progress. I grepped through the example apps, for example the gallery-app, but found nothing useful. Maybe too much work around-code-there also.

So what is the canonical (*schenkelklopf* ) way of stacking Tabs and some full screen Page?

I guess it's just not quite ready yet etc. and inconsistencies are a temporal state right now arising from the development rush of Ubuntu?

As an example I made up this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    width: units.gu(40)
    height: units.gu(71)
    PageStack {
        id: pageStack
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted: push(auberginePage)
        Tabs {
            id: auberginePage
            anchors.fill: parent
            Tab {
                title: "Awesome?"
                page: Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    visible: false
                    color: "#2C001E"
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent;
                        onClicked: pageStack.push(orangePage)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: orangePage
            color: "#DD4814"
            visible: false
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the time I asked everything has changed and the question isn't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the title of the page that you want to be in fullscreen mode to an empty string, like this:

```
Page {
    title: ""
}
```

Easy as that!

Comment: Can someone check this? I don't have the SDK these days, but want to mark the correct answer, if it is one.

Comment: Not working for me, I get a rather buggy blank title area that covers up part of my content when I set the `anchors.fill` to `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the `__showHeader` property and found it while reading other core apps.

```
pageStack.__showHeader = false
```

Hack not needed.

Comment: I've just tried to use this and got a deprecation warning. It didn't seem to work either. What's the correct way of doing this? Seeing as it's a core design pattern in the design guidelines there must be a supported way of doing it.

Comment: Since March 5 this has changed, I believe. Didn't looked into it yet.